# width should resize to 100% if there is only 1 section or else will continue with 50% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is 2 video section on my web page with 50% of width, which means 2 videos will appear in a single row, and what I want is when there is only 1 video then width of the section should resize to 100%, means (If there us only 1 video it will appear with 100% width, or else it will appear with 50% width) is it possible?

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes. it is possible. And we are not free code-writers. Please have a look at [mcve]

Comment: what you mean by "And we are not free code-writers",, do i have to pay something in order to get solution for this.?

Comment: No. you don't have to pay anything. But first you put some effort on it. Read the link I posted.

Comment: No, he means we are not here to write solutions for you, but to help you debug your code. It means that you have to try by yourself first :)

Comment: i already have tried doing all those thing but something is still missing and unable to find out that mistake.

Comment: show us what you tried, maybe we can help you to find and fix the mistake your made.

Comment: `i already have tried doing all those thing` - show what you tried. Nobody will judge you - and one learns from ones mistakes far more than just given free coding help

Comment: <div class="row">
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;"><iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe></div>
  <div style="float: left;"><iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe></div>
</div>


this are my codes

Comment: thanks,,, so is there anyone can help me with that? or can suggestion me how its gonna be done.??

Comment: So how many videos can there be, total, in a row?

Comment: I dont know.. it could be 1 or 2 or 3 or more than that, its upon users how many they can upload.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is our savior

Example with one, two and three videos :

```css
div.row{
  display: flex;
  width : 100%;
  justify-content : space-around;
  border : red dashed 2px;
  margin-bottom : 10px;
}
```

```html
<h3>With two videos : </h3>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<h3>With one video : </h3>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>


<h3>With three videos : </h3>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice try, but the problem is this video will come from the database which means its important to put all those videos in a single "row", as i can see above you have used 2 row.

Comment: No, these are two examples of the same thing. One with two videos, one with just one video, to show that it works in both cases. It works with N videos, for that matter. So yeah, nice try indeed :) Answer updated with one, two and three videos.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Finally i made it with the help of my senior below i have mentioned my example, this is what i was looking for.

                .card-group {
                    display: -webkit-box;
                    display: -webkit-flex;
                    display: -ms-flexbox;
                    display: flex;
                    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
                    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
                    flex-flow: row wrap
                }
                .card-group .card {
                    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                    -webkit-flex: 1 0 0%;
                    -ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
                    flex: 1 0 0%;
                    float:left;
                }                 

                .card iframe{
                    width:100%;
                    padding: 0 10px;
                    min-width:400px !important;
                    max-width:1200px !important;
                    border:0;
                }



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row margin-t20 card-group nopadding">
            <div class="card profilegallery"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe></div>
            <div class="card profilegallery"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe></div>
            <div class="card profilegallery"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe></div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using non-flex methods as well.

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.play {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.play:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.play:nth-child(2):last-child {
  width: 50%;
}

.play:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.play:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
.play:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<h1> 3 Videos
  <div class="row">
    <div class="play">
      <iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="play">
      <iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="play">
      <iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h1> 2 Videos
    <div class="row">
      <div class="play">
        <iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="play">
        <iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>


    <h1> 1 Video
      <div class="row">
        <div class="play">
          <iframe width="100%" src="youtube.com/embed/t83YU-vOwak"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
```